# Django user updates profile picture and the other users receive this changes too

Tags: django

I created a form so that every user can update its profile. What it's happening is that when a user changes the profile picture of its account, also it changes the profile picture of the other users and of course, I don't want that. This is my code:

signals.py

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

    if created:
        profile = Profile(user=instance)
        profile.save()

post_save.connect(create_user_profile,
                  sender=User,
                  dispatch_uid="profilecreation-signal")
```

forms.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "image",
            "description",
            "website"
        ]
```

views.py

```
def profile_page(request, username):
    form = ProfileForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)

    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
    context = {
     
        "profile_form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "profile.html", context)
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default="default.jpg", upload_to="profile_pics")
    description = models.TextField(default=None, max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=True, default="")
```

The profile_page view has username also as attribute because there is more code related to it.

Could someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to show your `Profile` model.

Comment: Okay. I've already edited it

Comment: Does the `profile_pics` folder have the correct image stored for each user?

Comment: I can see in the profile_pics folder the images stored but with a different font color, like grey (idk if this last comment is relevant)

Comment: Apparently the images for other users are not changed, but the wrong image is being displayed. When do you see the wrong image? When the other user is logged in?